# Delete 'Local Elements' Keychain and preventing it from coming back

Tags: mac, security, passwords

In Keychain, I have 3 keychains:

1. The 'login' keychain, which is secured by a password and that I can lock/unlock freely
2. The 'Local Elements' keychain, of unknown security, that I can not lock nor delete (locking just does nothing, deleting is greyed), and whose accepting my User password when I try to display one of its password, even if it doesn't display the password and just does nothing
3. The System Keychain.

All of the importants password are saved in the 'session' keychain, however, the accounts passwords of the account I added in the "Accounts" tab of System preferences are saved in the 'Local Elements' keychain. I'd like to have them stored by default in the secure 'login' keychain and permanently delete/render useless this unsecure 'Local Elements' keychain.

I tried emptying it and entering the passwords again, they stored themselves in the 'Local Elements' one again. I tried to remove the folder named after my mac UUID in the ~/Library/Keychain/ folder and rebooting. It simply deleted all the paswords in the Local Elements keychain but my account passwords kept storing themselve in this keychain.

How can I permanently delete this keychain so that my mail account passwords are stored in the 'login' keychain that I can lock/unlock at will?